# Select two points on a sphere such that the distance between them is maximized

Tags: calculus, euclidean-geometry

For reference, *Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Galaxy* says that “on Earth it is never possible to be farther than sixteen thousand miles from your birthplace”.

I am interested in how you would solve the general case. Given the radius of the sphere, how would you select two points such that the distance between them is maximized?

Comment: The $\max$ distance is $\pi R$, and since the $R \approx 4,000$ miles, this comes to a little over $12,500$ miles. So Douglas was correct, but he could have reduced the number.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a circle, the point farthest from your position is the diametrically opposed one. Similarly on a sphere.